# How to add an additional uniqueness field that contains the “Feed Item”’s associated “Owner feed nid” value?

Tags: feeds

The same “Feed Item”can belong to multiple “Feed Source”’s but only one of these “Feed Item”’s will ever be imported because the same “Feed Item”’s uniqueness field will always prevent any additional “Feed Item”’s from being generated.  The way to allow the same “Feed Item” that belongs to a different “Feed Source” to be generated would be to add an additional uniqueness field that contains the “Feed Item”’s associated “Owner feed nid” value.

Does anyone know how to add an additional uniqueness field that contains the “Feed Item”’s associated “Owner feed nid” value within the /admin/structure/feeds/rss_importer/mapping section?